# event handling in a radio button

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button

I want to display a hidden field when I make a particular selection using the radio button. Currently I have wriiten the code with onClick. But somehow it doesnt seem to be working for me.

```
   <td height = 20 valign = middle align = right width = 40%>Is the account enrolled for any checking package?</td>
   <td height = 20 valign = middle align = left width = 60%><input type = "radio" class="text1" name ="accEnrol" id ="accEnrolY" value = "Yes" onClick="accEnrol();">Yes <input type ="radio" class ="text1" name ="accEnrol" id ="accEnrolN" value ="No" onClick="accEnrol();"></input></td>

function accEnrol()
{
  if(document.getElementById('accEnrolY').checked)
{
  document.getElementById('packages').style.visibility='visible';
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('packages').style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

The strangest part is I have a similar piece of code for another radio button in the same file and that seems to be working without a hitch whereas this is not displaying the desired result. I cant seem to find where I am making the mistake.

The full jsp code is as follows:
``` <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
``<html>
``<head> ```
`<title>E-Form </title>`
`<script type="text/javascript">`

``` </script>
``<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" src="/Eform/JS/common.js"></SCRIPT> ```

`<link href='/Eform/CSS/common.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

``` <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
``<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
``</head> ```
`<body`

``` >
``<!--form action="/Eform/SendMail" method="post" id='Eform' name='Eform'--> ```
`<form action="/Eform/SendMail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='Eform' name='Eform'>`
    ``` <table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" ``class="text1"> ```

        `<tr>`
            `<td valign="middle">`
                ``` <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ``bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" class="commonText1"> ```

```
                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Account(Existing Customers) or Projected Monthly Balance(New Customers)``* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"> `
                        `<select tabindex="0" ``name="accOrBalType" id="accOrBalType" onchange="doClear();" class="text1">`
                            `<option selected` `value="">-- Select One & Enter a value in to text box below --</option>`
                            `<option ``value="1">Account(Existing Customers)</option>`
                            `<option ` `value="2">Projected Monthly Balance(New Customers)</option>`    
                        `</select>  `   
                    `</td>`
                `</tr>`
                `<tr id = "accountNumber" style = "visibility:hidden">`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Account Number* :</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"> <input type="text" class="text1" maxlength="20" name="accountNumber" size="20" ``onblur="selectFirst();" /></td> `
                `</tr>`
                `<tr id = "monthlyBalance" style `= "visibility:hidden">`
                    <td height="20" valign="middle"` `align="right" width="40%">Projected Monthly Balance* :</td>`
                    <td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"> <input type="text" class="text1" maxlength="20" name="monthlyBalance"  size="20" ``onblur="selectFirst();" /></td> `
                `</tr>
                `<tr id = "accEnrol" style = "visibility:hidden">`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Is the account already enrolled in a checking package or program?* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    <`td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"> <input type="radio" class="text1" name="accEnrol" id="accEnrolY" value="Yes" ``onclick="packageName();"> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" class="text1" name="enrol" id="accEnrolN" ``value="No" onclick="packageName();"> No</td> `
                `</tr>`
                `<tr id = "packages" style = "visibility:hidden">`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Package Name* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="100" class="text1" name="packages" size="50"/></td>`
                `</tr>`
                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Enrolled in Business Online* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    <td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"> <input type="radio" class="text1" name="enrol" value="Yes"> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp; `<input `type="radio" class="text1" name="enrol" value="No"> No</td> `
                `</tr>`
                                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Business Contact's First Name* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="15" class="text1" name="fName" id="fName" ``size="20" /></td>`
                `</tr>`
                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Business Contact's Last Name* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle"` `align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" maxlength="15" class="text1" name="lName" id="lName"` `size="20"/></td>`
                `</tr>`
                                                                            `<tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Telephone* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    <`td height="20" valign="middle"` `align="left" width="60%">`
                    `<input type="text" value=" +1-" size="1" ``readonly/>&nbsp;`
                        `<input type="text" ``maxlength="10" name="refTelephoneNo" id="refTelephoneNo" class="text1" size="11" />`
                    `</td>`
                `</tr>`
                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">Branch* :&nbsp;</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"><input type="text" class="text1" maxlength="80" name="branch" id="branch" ``size="20" /></td>`
                `</tr>`
                `<!--tr>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="right" width="40%">To mail Ids(semicolon separated)*</td>`
                    `<td height="20" valign="middle" ``align="left" width="60%"> <input type="text" class="text1" name="toList" id="toList" size="20" /></td>` 
                `</tr-->`
                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="10" align="center" ``width="40%"></td>`
                    <td height="10" align="center" `width="60%"></td> `
                `</tr>`
                `<tr>`
                    `<td align="right" width="40%">`
                        `<table border="0" ``cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">`
                            `<tr>`
                                `<td ``width="92%" height="5" align="right">`
                                    `<a target="_self" href="#" onclick="validateData('mail');" class="tryitbtn">Send Mail</a>`

                                `</td>`
                                `<td ``width="8%" height="5" align="left">`
                                    `<a target="_self" href="#" onclick="fnReset(document.forms[0]);" class="tryitbtn">Clear</a>`
                                `</td>`
                            <`/tr>`
                        `</table>`
                    `</td>`
                    `<td height="10" align="left" width="60%">`
                    `<a target="_self" href="#"` `onclick="validateData('preview');" class="tryitbtn">Preview</a>`
                    `</td> `
                `</tr>`
                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="10" align="center" ``width="40%"></td>`
                    `<td height="10" align="center" ``width="60%"></td> `
                `</tr>`

                `<tr>`
                    `<td height="10" align="center" width="40%">`
                        `<b>*</b> <FONT` `size="1">Indicates Mandatory Fields.</FONT></td>`
                    `<td height="10" align="center"` `width="60%"></td>` 
                `</tr>`
            `</table>`
        `</td>`
    `</tr>`
`</table>`
`</form>`
```

`</body>`
`</html>`

Comment: The function will need to be defined before the radio buttons

Comment: the function is in a seperate file and not on the jsp page. It is working fine for one other radio button on the same jsp

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to be working fine. Unless you are not using the function inside the script tags and also you forgot to close the the function at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was the mistake and it was pretty stupid actually. 
I changed the function name from accEnrol() to programName because the tag name and the function name were similar which I guess apparently created the problem. I kept getting the error - Object doesnt support this property or method. Now that I have unique names for everything, it works fine!!
Thanks a lot y'all for all the help and time!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your markup, and closed the function and this works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>

    window.onload = function()
    {
      accEnrol = function ()
      {
        if(document.getElementById('accEnrolY').checked)
        {
          document.getElementById('packages').style.visibility='visible';
        }
        else
        {
          document.getElementById('packages').style.visibility='hidden';
        }
      }
    }

  </script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
   <td height = 20 valign = middle align = right width = 40%>Is the account enrolled for any checking package?</td>
      <td height = 20 valign = middle align = left width = 60%><input type = "radio" class="text1" name ="accEnrol" id ="accEnrolY" value = "Yes" onClick="accEnrol();"/>Yes <input type ="radio" class ="text1" name ="accEnrol" id ="accEnrolN" value ="No" onClick="accEnrol();"/></td>
  </tr>
    <div id="packages">Here am I</div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**jsBin**: http://jsbin.com/ayarar/1/edit

Comment: since this code is on my remote system i actually typed it out here. It is a typo.

Comment: @LalithaSairaman post the whole relevant code. Where is the packages element in the provided code?

Comment: the accEnrol function is present in a seperate file whereas the packages element is actually a text field present in the jsp page same as the accEnrol radio buttons.
<tr id = "packages" style="visibility:hidden">
<td height="20" valign = "middle" align = "right" width = "40%">Package Name </td>
<td height = "20" valign = "middle" align = "left" width = "60%"><input type="text" class= "text1" maxlength = "20" name = "packages" size = "20"></td>

Comment: it still doesnt work for me :-( is there anything else like browser version or something like that which might cause this not to work? because i am befuddled

Comment: I dont have enough rep to join the chat room.. Joined stackflow just a week back :-P

Answer (score 0):

Here is the slight modification of the OP's code.

```
<!--ADD THIS IN THE CODE-->
<div id='packages'>
enter your codes here
</div>

<td height = 20 valign = middle align = right width = 40%>
    Is the account enrolled for any checking package?
</td>
<td height = 20 valign = middle align = left width = 60%>
    <input type = "radio" class="text1" name ="accEnrol" id ="accEnrolY" value = "Yes" onClick="accEnrol();">Yes</input> 
    <input type ="radio" class ="text1" name ="accEnrol" id ="accEnrolN" value ="No" onClick="accEnrol();">No </input>
</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
function accEnrol(){
    if(document.getElementById('accEnrolY').checked){
        document.getElementById('packages').style.visibility='visible';
        alert ("checked");
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('packages').style.visibility='hidden';
        alert ("unchecked");
    }
}    //This is the part you were missing.
</script>
```

I have added the alert messages to check if you are getting the desired output.

**Here are the snap shots of the above codes**
[image: These are the codes in netbeans.]
**Initial display when you get to the page**
[image: This is the initial display when you get to that page]

**Display when clicked on No**

[image: The alert appears when you clicked no and hides the contents of the container with id='packages']
[image: The alert with 'checked' message appears when you click on yes and the contents of the container with id='packages' are displayed again]

I do not understand why it is not working for you. I would be helpful if you could post the actual codes where you have those id='packages' set up. The only reason I could think of is the issue of duplicate ids. If you have two ids with the same name under the same scope then the javascript will not recognize which one to pull from.

Comment: for some reason the function is not getting called at all. neither of the alerts popped up

Comment: It won't work because you do not have a container with 'packages' tagged id. I just tested it and seems to work fine. I will modify the code for you.

Comment: i do have a packages container and that is the one i want to make visible. It doesnt work

Comment: i am actually getting an error which states object doesnt support this property or method. I am getting hit by this near the accEnrol id

Comment: Can you post your codes please. Even if it is in the remoter server you should be able to view the source codes from the page as these are client side scripts. Other wise I will not be able to pinpoint what is wrong with your code.